# Template argument calculation at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to deduce the greater of two template arguments at compile time. Both template arguments are of type size_t.

I have a templated type, SomeType, which takes a size_t as it's template argument. I then have a function that takes two SomeType parameters with different template size_t's and i want the return type to be a SomeType with its templated size_t to be the greater of the two input size_t sizes.

```
template <size_t d> struct SomeType {...}

template<size_t d1, size_t d2>
SomeType<the_larger_of_d1_and_d2> Func(SomeType<d1> A, SomeType<d2> B)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are the arguments known at compile-time?

Comment: d1 and d2 are known, A and B are not.

Comment: In general **it is** possible. If you're using the older [tag:c++03] standard you'll have to implement a type selector template class, that specializes to provide a `typedef`, for either `class A` or `class B` and specialize it for `true` or `false` from the condition you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the type directly, no need for SFINAE:

```
template<size_t d1, size_t d2>
SomeType<(d1 > d2 ? d1 : d2)> Func(SomeType<d1> A, SomeType<d2> B)
{
    …
}
```

Comment: Usage of the ternary `?:` operator for selection from a particular boolean condition is a really nice shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @KonradRudolph is correct of course. But if you want to delve further in to template metaprogramming, it would pay-off very quickly to learn [**Boost.MPL**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/mpl/doc/). It provides a whole battery of convenience functions. E.g. your question can be solved like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/max.hpp>

template<size_t d> 
struct SomeType
: 
    boost::mpl::int_<d> 
{};

template<size_t d1, size_t d2>
typename boost::mpl::max<SomeType<d1>, SomeType<d2> >::type
Func(SomeType<d1> A, SomeType<d2> B) 
{
    return typename boost::mpl::max<SomeType<d1>, SomeType<d2> >::type();
}

int main()
{
    SomeType<2> st2;
    SomeType<3> st3;
    boost::mpl::max<SomeType<2>, SomeType<3> >::type res = Func(st2, st3);
    std::cout << res.value;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f058af9147561884).

Some notes:

- letting `SomeType` inherit from `boost::mpl::int_` endows it with a `type` and `value`, as well as some convenient tags. This makes it very easy to re-use other metafunctions from Boost.MPL
- the `boost::mpl::max` does the same ternary trick behind the scenes. It is more readible IMO, and if you ever want to change to another condition it's easy to do so.
- there is a bit of a learning curve for Boost.MPL, but the tutorial at the linked documentation should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard, you can use SFINAE standard support:

```
template<size_t one, size_t two>
struct larger {
    static constexpr typename std::enable_if<(one > two), size_t>::type value() {
        return one;
    }

    static constexpr typename std::enable_if<(two >= one, size_t>::type value() {
        return two;
    }
};
```

Then

```
template<size_t d1, size_t d2>
SomeType<larger<d1, d2>::value()> Func(SomeType<d1> A, SomeType<d2> B)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: uhm... `constexpr size_t larger(size_t a, size_t b) { return a < b : b : a; }` seems simpler than that meta function if you have C++11. It can be generalized to anything other than `size_t` by making it a template. SFINAE is a nice tool that should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm constantly have to look up myself (my older code) about that question again and again, I've decided to make a [GIT gist](https://gist.github.com/makulik/8943582), and [compilation sample](http://ideone.com/thoOMw) that allows (at least me) to quickly access some 'template' code (pun intended), to play with the meta-programmed conditional type selection stuff (also working for the 'old' [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) standard):

**Selector declaration:**

```
template<typename FalseType, typename TrueType, bool condition>
struct ConditionalTypeSelector {
    typedef void ResultType;
};
```

---

**Selector specialization(s):**

```
template<typename FalseType, typename TrueType>
struct ConditionalTypeSelector<FalseType,TrueType,false> {
    typedef FalseType ResultType;
};

template<typename FalseType, typename TrueType>
struct ConditionalTypeSelector<FalseType,TrueType,true> {
    typedef TrueType ResultType;
};
```

---

**Selected types:**

```
struct A {
    unsigned char member;
};

struct B {
    int member;
};

struct C {
    long long member;
};
```

---

**Testing:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << typeid
                ( ConditionalTypeSelector
                      < A,B,(sizeof(A) > sizeof(B))>::ResultType
                ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid
                ( ConditionalTypeSelector
                      <A,B,(sizeof(B) > sizeof(A)) >::ResultType
                ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid
                ( ConditionalTypeSelector
                      < A,C,(sizeof(A) > sizeof(C))>::ResultType
                ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid
                ( ConditionalTypeSelector
                      < C,B,true>::ResultType
                ).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid
                ( ConditionalTypeSelector
                      < C,A,false>::ResultType
                ).name() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's pretty easy to change this `template` to use e.g. an `enum` type for specialized selections, or whatever else constant condition known at compile time should be checked.