# Templating on Enum Value to Select Handle Open/Close

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

I am writing a C++ wrapper for a C library that works with handles represented by integers. There are a bunch of open functions (Aopen, Bopen, Copen, Dopen, Eopen, ...) and corresponding close functions (Aclose, Bclose, Cclose, Dclose, Eclose, ...). I currently have wrapper classes implementing basic RAII, but I have a bit of code duplication, as each of these wrappers differs only in which open and close routine it calls. To get rid of this duplication I was thinking of templating on an enum I define with values for each of the routines (e.g. Atype, Bytpe, etc), and then selecting the correct open and close function at compile time. It would like something like:

```
TypeWrapper<AType> wrapped_a(...)
TypeWrapper<BType> wrapped_b(...)
...
```

Is this a reasonable approach, is there a simpler approach, or is there a name for this type of construction?

Thank you!

Comment: You could just inherit from a common base class and only override the open and close functions. This way you would get rid of code duplication.

Comment: True, that would definitely work. It seems like there is enough information here to do this at compile time, though, so it should be possible to avoid vtable calls. Definitely premature optimization -- I suppose I am asking more for intellectual curiosity.

Comment: I've once written an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712722/1413395), that could point into the right direction. Also you should improve your question with a more complete sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like the following:

```
template <typename H, H Open(const char*), void Close(H)>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(const char* file) : h(Open(file)) {}
    ~Wrapper() { Close(h); }

    Wrapper(const Wrapper&) = delete;
    Wrapper& operator = (const Wrapper&) = delete;
private:
    H h;
};
```

And then `using Wrapper_A = Wrapper<AHandle, AOpen, AClose>;`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/bBhxee)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Template Specialization.

Basically, this is done by templating your TypeWrapper class on an enum value, then providing specialized implementations for the open/close calls for each enum value.

An example is worth a thousand words: [live example](http://ideone.com/Q6gb23)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Type {
    AType = 0,
    BType,
    CType,
};

void AOpen() { std::cout << "A open." << std::endl; }
void BOpen() { std::cout << "B open." << std::endl; }
void COpen() { std::cout << "C open." << std::endl; }

template<Type T>
class TypeWrapper {
    public:
    void open();
    void close();
};

template<>
void TypeWrapper<AType>::open() { AOpen(); }

template<>
void TypeWrapper<BType>::open() { BOpen(); }

template<>
void TypeWrapper<CType>::open() { COpen(); }

int main() {
    TypeWrapper<AType> wrapped_a;
    TypeWrapper<BType> wrapped_b;
    wrapped_a.open();
    wrapped_b.open();
    return 0;
}
```